# Laravel eloquent and query with two join tables criterias

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Here the situation.

I have a `user` table, a `role` table (different users can have the same role) and a `post` table (different users can be linked to a same post - multi authors post). I also have two join tables that link `user` and `role` and `user` and `post`. I have built all relationships (many-to-many).

But now I try to get all users that have a particular `role` ('id' = 2 for example) and have contributed to a particular post ('id' = 45 for example).

I can do it with one criteria :

```
$roles = App\Role::where('id', 2)->first();
foreach ($roles->users as $user) {

}
```

But I didn't find the solution with two criterias (`role` id and `post` id).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use relationship existence to to achieve your goal. And the `whereHas()` function is for checking relationship existence.

**Assuming that you have defined relationships on models**

```php
$roleId = 2;
$postId = 45;

$users = User::whereHas('role', function($query) use ($roleId) {
    $query->where('id', $roleId);
})
->whereHas('post', function ($query) use ($postId) {
    $query->where('id', $postId);
})
->get();
```